# Unknown network "ganache". See your Truffle configuration file for available networks

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I am working windows 10 and have both

> truffle.js

&

> truffle-config.js

I am using command

> truffle migrate --reset --networks rinkeby
>
> Error produced: Unknown network "ganache". See your Truffle
>   configuration file for available networks. Truffle v5.0.19 (core:
>   5.0.19)

Here's my truffle configuration:

```
 networks: {

      development: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 7545,
        network_id: "5777", // Match any network id
        from: "0x55690752ed06B1d37510D20B3516b2D12F007f6d"
      },

      rinkeby: {
        provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, infura),
        network_id: 4,
        gas: 6700000,
        gasPrice : 10000000000
      }
  },
```

The configurations are same for both truffle.js & truffle-config.js

Comment: To begin with, on Windows, get rid of `truffle.js` if you want to be able to run `truffle...` command line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure an answer is no longer needed for this, but in case anyone else has the same problem, `--networks` should be `--network`.

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
truffle deploy —network <network-name> —reset
```

And only use truffle-config.js if you r in windows.